# Javascript / Jquery OOP not inheriting attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, constructor, encapsulation

I have created a Constructor class / function that has 4 methods and a 5 attributes. The problem is when i create a new instance of the constructor it doesn't inherit the first attribute (this.el = element) which is 'affiliateSection' on the new instance called: animation1. Thanks in advance..

```
// main class
function AnimateImages(el, time, effect, setTime, h){

    this.el = element; // this is not inheriting from 'animate1'
    this.time = time;
    this.effect = effect;
    this.setTime = setTime;
    this.h = height;

    this.delayAnimate = function() {
        this.element.delay(time)
            .queue(function(next) {
                $(this).addClass(effect);
                next();
            });
    };

    // function for multi animations
    var multiAnimations = function() {
        var i = 0;
        this.element.each(function (key, value) {
            i = i + setTime;
            var tthis = this;
            delayAnimate($(this), i, tthis.effect);
        });
    };

    // load on window height
    var onWindowAnimate = function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > this.height) {
            // call multi animations function
            var tthis = this;
            multiAnimations(this.element, tthis.setTime, tthis.effect);
        }
    };
    // hide function
    var hideAnimatedEl = function (){
        this.element.each(function(){

            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
    };
} // End of AnimateImages

/*============================================================*/

 var affiliateSection = $("#aff-img > li > img");
 // new instance of AnimateImages
 var animation1 = new AnimateImages(affiliateSection, 200, 'subtlefadeIn', 
  300, 50);


 $(window).scroll(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        animation1.onWindowAnimate();

      }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: the expected parameter is `el`, not `element` : `this.el = el`

Comment: `this.el = element;` ? Where is `element` defined ?

Comment: voting to close as typo.

Comment: Just realised I have it the wrong way round , thanks, yep should change all my elements to el, thanks!

Comment: You seem to want `this.element = el;`

Comment: yes! this.element = el;, thanks!

Comment: Aside from `this.el`, you also went wrong with `this.h = height;` which should be `this.h = h;`

Comment: thanks! i also fixed my methods, i was converting a few functions into OOP and totally didnt realsie i had my defined properties the wrong way around, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your member variable initializations backwards.  Try this:

```
this.element = el; // this is not inheriting from 'animate1'
this.time = time;
this.effect = effect;
this.setTime = setTime;
this.height = h;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name is wrong:

```
this.el = element;
```

`element` is not in the parameter list.

Since you are reffering to `this.element` inside your function, I am assuming that your first line should be

```
this.element = el;
```

Comment: Same for `this.h = height;`